# test existing Apache Camel route

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I'm trying to unit test my existing routes by extending CamelTestSupport and overriding createRouteBuilder(). I get IllegalArgumentException: camelContext must be specified. Can anyone help?

```
public class RutaArchivarItemsTest extends CamelTestSupport{

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
protected MockEndpoint jpaArchivo;

@Produce(uri = "direct:jpaArchivoPieza")
protected ProducerTemplate template;

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    RutaArchivarItems rutaArchivarItems = new RutaArchivarItems();
    rutaArchivarItems.offset = 24;
    rutaArchivarItems.habilitado = true;
    return rutaArchivarItems;
}

@Test
public void piezaParaArchivar() throws Exception {
    EventoPieza eventoPieza = new EventoPieza("AA","TN030", IpsEvent.IpsVersion.v2015.name(),"test");
    ArchivoEventos archivoEventos = new ArchivoEventos(eventoPieza);
    jpaArchivo.expectedBodiesReceived(archivoEventos);

    template.sendBody(eventoPieza);
    jpaArchivo.expectedBodyReceived();
}
```

EDIT:

So, if I replace createRouteBuilder() with:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    context.addRoutes(new RutaArchivarItems(){
        @Override
        public void intialize() {
            habilitado = true;
            offset = 24;

        }
    });
}
```

I get a different error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named camel, in this line: context.addRoutes(new RutaArchivarItems(){. So I guess I should bind em field somehow...

Comment: Well your problem was that you had no routes specified before and the Camelcontext was not loaded..which resulted in the first error. But what exactly are you trying to do? Connect to a database and do some operations?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Routes are defined in a class (RutaArchivarItems) that extends RouteBuilder, i'm traying to load those routes by overriding createRouteBuilder(). I just want to test existing routes, i was thinking in using adviceWith to replace jpaEndpoints with mockEndpoints but i can't even get there.